# Использование сенсоров освещенности и акселерометра

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Вот нужно, чтобы в программе выполнялись следующие действия:
1) Датчик освещенности - при высоком (ярком) уровне освещенности, делать экран ярче, при низком - тусклее.
2) Акселерометр или компас - для изменения ориентации экрана в зависимости от данных акселерометра / направления компаса (Landscape, LandscapeFlipped, Portrait, PortraitFlipped).

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Hardware;

namespace L2.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "L2", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)] // всегда портретная ориентация
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, Android.Hardware.ISensorEventListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            var sensorService = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);
            var lightSensor = sensorService.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Light);
            var accelerometerSensor = sensorService.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);
            sensorService.RegisterListener(this, lightSensor, Android.Hardware.SensorDelay.Game);
            sensorService.RegisterListener(this, accelerometerSensor, Android.Hardware.SensorDelay.Game);
        }

        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent s)
        {
            if (s.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Light)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Датчик света" + s.Values[0]);
            }
            else if (s.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Accelerometer)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Акселерометр" + s.Values[0] + " " + s.Values[1] + " " + s.Values[2]);
            }
        }

        public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, SensorStatus accuracy)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот нужно при изменении значений датчиков в методе public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent s) соответственно изменять яркость и оринтацию но как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужны соответствующие Api

Comment: Вы можете пример привести

Comment: настройка яркости
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically смена ориентации экрана
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button

Comment: Не получается так я добавил полный код там нужно внести изменения в метод OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent s)